# Passing an array of parameters as a request body in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to pass an array of parameters that looks like this:

```
{
   "watermarks": [
       {
            "email" : "correo_user",
            "event_type" : "app",
            "watermark" : "marcaAgua",
            "date" : "date",
            "location" : "location",
            "segment" : 1,
            "time" : "time",
            "country" : "country",
            "city" : "city"
       }
   ]
}
```

I don't know how to pass it as an array of objects because I have never done it before. This is the code that I'm currently using:

```
func marcaAgua(parameters: [String: Any],
                   completion: @escaping (Result<[MarcaAguaResData], Error>)-> Void) {
        
        let urlString =  baseUrl + "events"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badUrl))
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Bearer \(token_login)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let unwrappedResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                    completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badResponse))
                    return
                }
                
                switch unwrappedResponse.statusCode {
                case 200 ..< 300:
                    print("success")
                default:
                    print("failure")
                }
                
                if let unwrappedError = error {
                    completion(.failure(unwrappedError))
                    return
                }
                
                if let unwrappedData = data {
                    
                    print("QQQQQ")
                    print(unwrappedData)
                    
                    do{
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData, options:.allowFragments)

                        if let successRes = try? JSONDecoder().decode([MarcaAguaResData].self, from: unwrappedData){
                            completion(.success(successRes))
                        }else{

                            let errorResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode([MarcaAguaErrorResponse].self, from: unwrappedData)
                            print("Error \(errorResponse)")
                            completion(.failure(errorResponse as! Error))
                        }
                    }catch{
                        print("AAA")
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

When I pass the parameters to the function when I call it, I pass them as a dictionary of type [String:Any]. This is an example of it:

```
let signupQueryData : [String : Any] = [
            "watermarks": [
                "email" : correo_user as String,
                "event_type" : "app" as String,
                "watermark" : marcaAgua as String,
                "date" : "\(dateActual) \(hour):\(minutes)" as String,
                "location" : latitudYLongitud as String,
                "segment" : 1 as Int,
                "time" : "\(hour):\(minutes)" as String,
                "country" : "\(qlq)" as String,
                "city" : "Caracas" as String
            ]
        ]
```

And this is what it prints of parameters in the function marcaAgua:

```
["watermarks": ["time": "22:10", "segment": 1, "location": "location", "email": "mail", "event_type": "app", "watermark": "e356eaadcb3aa4a1049441fc48d83a22", "date": "13.07.2021 22:10", "country": "Venezuela", "city": "Caracas"]]
```

When I do that, I get the following error:

```
failure(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})
```

Comment: The following line doesn't make sense.  request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: [parameters])

Comment: Why are you saying that?

Comment: you used query item data just pass that in body like `request.httpBody = queryItemsData`

Comment: Please show us the API spec. Whatever you send in the body of the POST request, needs to be in the exact form and content type the backend expects. For example, you showed us a JSON Object, containing one element "watermarks". You can send the object or the array or the object wrapped in an array, but unless you show us what the backend expects, you cannot expect an answer that helps.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper that is what the backend expects! The first chunk of code is what the service is expecting as parameters. That is an example of what has to be passed

Comment: @jatinfl I deleted that code, it doesn't work for me. I updated the question

Comment: Look at the `Codable` protocol. It will make JSON serialization much easier and arrays are a breeze (much better than `JsonSerialization).

Comment: Answering your answer to my comment: you are nowhere sending any "parameters". You are sending "application/json" which is data, precisely JSON. In your code this is a JSON Object - and can contain basically everything. Your example JSON is a JSON Object, too, but more precisely, with one element named "watermark" which is a JSON Array, containing one JSON Object with a couple elements all being JSON Strings. If your example JSON is exactly what the server expects AND your JSON Object is in this form, you are done already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try do like this

```
func marcaAgua(parameters: [String: Any],
                   completion: @escaping (Result<[MarcaAguaResData], Error>)-> Void) {
        
        let urlString =  baseUrl + "events"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badUrl))
            return
        }
        
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("Bearer \(token_login)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let unwrappedResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                completion(.failure(NetworkingError.badResponse))
                return
            }
            
            switch unwrappedResponse.statusCode {
            case 200 ..< 300:
                print("success")
            default:
                print("failure")
            }
            
            if let unwrappedError = error {
                completion(.failure(unwrappedError))
                return
            }
            
            if let unwrappedData = data {
                do{
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData, options:.allowFragments)
                    
                    if let successRes = try? JSONDecoder().decode([MarcaAguaResData].self, from: unwrappedData){
                        completion(.success(successRes))
                    }else{
                        
                        let errorResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode([MarcaAguaErrorResponse].self, from: unwrappedData)
                        completion(.failure(errorResponse as! Error))
                    }
                }catch{
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

initialise Variables

```
var invitationsArray = Array<[String: Any]>()
var invitations = Array<[String: Any]>()
```

Logic

```
    invitations = [["friend_id": "\(each.friendId!)", "invited_type": "friend"]]
                    invitationsArray.append(contentsOf: invitations)
```

Set variables

```
let params: [String: Any] = [
            "user_id":Global.shared.currentUserLogin.id,
            "ride_name": planARide.name!,
            "ride_description": planARide.description!,
            "ride_type": planARide.rideType!,
            "ride_date_and_time": planARide.rideDate!,
            "ride_city": planARide.city!,
            "ride_meeting_spot": planARide.rideMeetingSpot!,
            "ride_meeting_latitude": planARide.latitude!,
            "ride_meeting_longitude": planARide.longitude!,
            "ride_intensity": planARide.rideIntensity!,
            "time_length_of_ride": planARide.rideTime!,
            "reoccuring_ride": planARide.rideReccurring!,
            "special_instructions": planARide.specialInstruction!,
            "open_ride_to_biking_community": planARide.openRideToBikingCommunity!,
            "invitations": invitationsArray
        ]
```

Comment: I tried that but didn't work. I updated the question with the things I'm getting